# Skipping Characters in Regex

Tags: ruby, regex

I have the following data

```
Animals = Dog Cat Turtle \
          Mouse Parrot \
          Snake
```

I would like the regex to construct a match of just the animals with none of the backslashes: `Dog Cat Turtle Mouse Parrot Snake`

I've got a regex, but need some help finishing it off.

```
/ANIMALS\s*=\s*([^\\\n]*)/
```

Comment: Why not just strip the \ out of your data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How 'bout the regex `\b(?!Animals\b)\w+\b` which matches all words that aren't `Animals`?  Use the `scan` method to collect all such matches, e.g.

```
matchArray = sourceString.scan(/\b(?!Animals\b)\w+\b/)
```

Comment: Thanks, this isn't quite exactly what I needed but it helped put me in the right direction.

Answer (score 3):

Since you specified a language, I need to ask you this: Why are you relying on the regex for everything? Don't make the problem harder than it has to be by forcing the regex to do everything.

Try this approach instead...

1. Use `gsub!` to get rid of the backslashes.
2. `split` the string on any whitespace.
3. Shift out the first two tokens ("Animals", "=").
4. Join the array with a single space, or whatever other delimiter.

So the only regex you might need is one for the whitespace delimiter split. I don't know Ruby well enough to say exactly how you would do that, though.

Comment: +1 agreed. Use the right tool for the job. Not everything needs regex.

Comment: Because the data is lot more simplified than what I stated. I can't use gsub! because I'm parsing a whole file. This was just a small snippet of sample text.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are matching with ignore-case, because ANIMALS will not match Animals without it.